# when and how to use nested command substitution in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to linux and want to know how nested command substitution works and when to use them in shell script.

I have tried below examples to list the contents of current directory:

example 1:

```
content=$(ls -ltr pwd)

echo $content
```

error:
 pwd :not a file or directory

Above didn't work ,my expectation was that command substitution will execute "pwd" command like it do "ls -ltr".

example 2:

```
content=$(ls -ltr $(pwd))

echo $content
```

Here we used nested command substitution.so this worked.

I want to know when to use nested command substitution and it's working?
can anyone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

In bash, `$(cmd)` will be substituted with the standard output of `cmd`, so if you run `ls $(pwd)` in `/tmp` it will turn into `ls /tmp`.

The reason the first example did not work is because bash did not know your intention was to run `pwd` and substitute it in. What it ended up executing is `ls -ltr pwd` and `ls` tried to list the contents of the directory `pwd`, which does not exist.